# Как получить значение protected свойства из объекта php

Tags: php, битрикс

Не могу получить значение телефон из вот такого массива - /bonus_log.php (смотрите в самом конце, я там пометила строчку):

```html
int(7817)
string(1) "Y"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValue)#1785 (6) {
 ...
  [1]=>
  object(Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValue)#1687 (6) {
    ["property":protected]=>
    object(Bitrix\Sale\Property)#1689 (1) {
      ["fields":protected]=>
      array(24) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["PERSON_TYPE_ID"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["NAME"]=>
        string(14) "Телефон"
        ["TYPE"]=>
        string(6) "STRING"
        ["REQUIRED"]=>
        string(1) "Y"
        ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["SORT"]=>
        string(3) "120"
        ["USER_PROPS"]=>
        string(1) "Y"
        ["IS_LOCATION"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["PROPS_GROUP_ID"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["IS_EMAIL"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["IS_PROFILE_NAME"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["IS_PAYER"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["IS_LOCATION4TAX"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["IS_FILTERED"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["CODE"]=>
        string(5) "PHONE"
        ["IS_ZIP"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["IS_PHONE"]=>
        string(1) "Y"
        ["IS_ADDRESS"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["ACTIVE"]=>
        string(1) "Y"
        ["UTIL"]=>
        string(1) "N"
        ["INPUT_FIELD_LOCATION"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["MULTIPLE"]=>
        string(1) "N"
      }
    }
    ["collection":protected]=>
    object(Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValueCollection)#1620 (6) {
      ["order":protected]=>
      object(Bitrix\Sale\Order)#1640 (19) {
        ["shipmentCollection":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["paymentCollection":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["tradeBindingCollection":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["printedChecks":protected]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["calculatedFields":protected]=>
        object(Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields)#1787 (4) {
          ["values":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["changedValues":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["originalValues":"Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields":private]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["isClone":protected]=>
          bool(false)
        }
        ["basketCollection":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["propertyCollection":protected]=>
        *RECURSION*
        ["discount":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["tax":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["internalId":protected]=>
        int(0)
        ["isNew":protected]=>
        bool(false)
        ["isSaveExecuting":protected]=>
        bool(false)
        ["isClone":protected]=>
        bool(false)
        ["isOnlyMathAction":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["isMeaningfulField":protected]=>
        bool(false)
        ["isStartField":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["calculateType":protected]=>
        string(1) "C"
        ["fields":protected]=>
        object(Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields)#1635 (4) {
          ["values":protected]=>
          array(67) {
            ["ID"]=>
            string(4) "7817"
            ["LID"]=>
            string(2) "s1"
            ["ACCOUNT_NUMBER"]=>
            string(4) "7817"
            ["TRACKING_NUMBER"]=>
            NULL
            ["PAY_SYSTEM_ID"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["DELIVERY_ID"]=>
            string(1) "3"
            ["DATE_INSERT"]=>
            object(Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime)#1621 (1) {
              ["value":protected]=>
              object(DateTime)#1624 (3) {
                ["date"]=>
                string(26) "2021-01-18 11:43:53.000000"
                ["timezone_type"]=>
                int(3)
                ["timezone"]=>
                string(18) "Asia/Yekaterinburg"
              }
            }
            ["DATE_UPDATE"]=>
            object(Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime)#1622 (1) {
              ["value":protected]=>
              object(DateTime)#1619 (3) {
                ["date"]=>
                string(26) "2021-01-19 14:10:50.000000"
                ["timezone_type"]=>
                int(3)
                ["timezone"]=>
                string(18) "Asia/Yekaterinburg"
              }
            }
            ["PERSON_TYPE_ID"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["USER_ID"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["PAYED"]=>
            string(1) "Y"
            ["DATE_PAYED"]=>
            object(Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime)#1623 (1) {
              ["value":protected]=>
              object(DateTime)#1626 (3) {
                ["date"]=>
                string(26) "2021-01-19 14:10:50.000000"
                ["timezone_type"]=>
                int(3)
                ["timezone"]=>
                string(18) "Asia/Yekaterinburg"
              }
            }
            ["EMP_PAYED_ID"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["DEDUCTED"]=>
            string(1) "N"
            ["DATE_DEDUCTED"]=>
            NULL
            ["EMP_DEDUCTED_ID"]=>
            NULL
            ["REASON_UNDO_DEDUCTED"]=>
            NULL
            ["STATUS_ID"]=>
            string(1) "P"
            ["DATE_STATUS"]=>
            object(Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime)#1630 (1) {
              ["value":protected]=>
              object(DateTime)#1634 (3) {
                ["date"]=>
                string(26) "2021-01-18 11:44:56.000000"
                ["timezone_type"]=>
                int(3)
                ["timezone"]=>
                string(18) "Asia/Yekaterinburg"
              }
            }
            ["EMP_STATUS_ID"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["MARKED"]=>
            string(1) "N"
            ["DATE_MARKED"]=>
            NULL
            ["EMP_MARKED_ID"]=>
            NULL
            ["REASON_MARKED"]=>
            NULL
            ["PRICE_DELIVERY"]=>
            float(0)
            ["ALLOW_DELIVERY"]=>
            string(1) "N"
            ["DATE_ALLOW_DELIVERY"]=>
            NULL
            ["EMP_ALLOW_DELIVERY_ID"]=>
            NULL
            ["RESERVED"]=>
            string(1) "N"
            ["PRICE"]=>
            float(910)
            ["CURRENCY"]=>
            string(3) "RUB"
            ["DISCOUNT_VALUE"]=>
            float(0)
            ["TAX_VALUE"]=>
            string(4) "0.00"
            ["SUM_PAID"]=>
            float(910)
            ["USER_DESCRIPTION"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["PAY_VOUCHER_NUM"]=>
            NULL
            ["PAY_VOUCHER_DATE"]=>
            object(Bitrix\Main\Type\Date)#1643 (1) {
              ["value":protected]=>
              object(DateTime)#1744 (3) {
                ["date"]=>
                string(26) "2021-01-19 00:00:00.000000"
                ["timezone_type"]=>
                int(3)
                ["timezone"]=>
                string(18) "Asia/Yekaterinburg"
              }
            }
            ["ADDITIONAL_INFO"]=>
            NULL
            ["COMMENTS"]=>
            NULL
            ["COMPANY_ID"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["CREATED_BY"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["RESPONSIBLE_ID"]=>
            NULL
            ["STAT_GID"]=>
            NULL
            ["DATE_PAY_BEFORE"]=>
            NULL
            ["DATE_BILL"]=>
            NULL
            ["IS_RECURRING"]=>
            string(1) "N"
            ["RECURRING_ID"]=>
            NULL
            ["LOCKED_BY"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["DATE_LOCK"]=>
            object(Bitrix\Main\Type\DateTime)#1636 (1) {
              ["value":protected]=>
              object(DateTime)#1633 (3) {
                ["date"]=>
                string(26) "2021-01-19 14:10:42.000000"
                ["timezone_type"]=>
                int(3)
                ["timezone"]=>
                string(18) "Asia/Yekaterinburg"
              }
            }
            ["RECOUNT_FLAG"]=>
            string(1) "Y"
            ["AFFILIATE_ID"]=>
            NULL
            ["DELIVERY_DOC_NUM"]=>
            NULL
            ["DELIVERY_DOC_DATE"]=>
            NULL
            ["UPDATED_1C"]=>
            string(1) "N"
            ["ORDER_TOPIC"]=>
            NULL
            ["XML_ID"]=>
            string(16) "bx_60052e2973c81"
            ["ID_1C"]=>
            NULL
            ["VERSION_1C"]=>
            NULL
            ["VERSION"]=>
            string(2) "26"
            ["EXTERNAL_ORDER"]=>
            string(1) "N"
            ["STORE_ID"]=>
            NULL
            ["CANCELED"]=>
            string(1) "N"
            ["EMP_CANCELED_ID"]=>
            NULL
            ["DATE_CANCELED"]=>
            NULL
            ["REASON_CANCELED"]=>
            NULL
            ["BX_USER_ID"]=>
            string(32) "0263c18444b96c3246aeae0a229fe844"
            ["RUNNING"]=>
            string(1) "N"
          }
          ["changedValues":protected]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["originalValues":"Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields":private]=>
          array(0) {
          }
          ["isClone":protected]=>
          bool(false)
        }
        ["eventName":protected]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["propertyGroups":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["index":"Bitrix\Sale\Internals\EntityCollection":private]=>
      int(23)
      ["isClone":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["anyItemDeleted":protected]=>
      bool(false)
      ["collection":protected]=>
      array(24) {
        [0]=>
        object(Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValue)#1785 (6) {
          ["property":protected]=>
          object(Bitrix\Sale\Property)#1727 (1) {
            ["fields":protected]=>
            array(25) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["PERSON_TYPE_ID"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["NAME"]=>
              string(6) "Имя"
              ["TYPE"]=>
              string(6) "STRING"
              ["REQUIRED"]=>
              string(1) "Y"
              ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["SORT"]=>
              string(3) "100"
              ["USER_PROPS"]=>
              string(1) "Y"
              ["IS_LOCATION"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["PROPS_GROUP_ID"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["IS_EMAIL"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_PROFILE_NAME"]=>
              string(1) "Y"
              ["IS_PAYER"]=>
              string(1) "Y"
              ["IS_LOCATION4TAX"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_FILTERED"]=>
              string(1) "Y"
              ["CODE"]=>
              string(3) "FIO"
              ["IS_ZIP"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_PHONE"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_ADDRESS"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["ACTIVE"]=>
              string(1) "Y"
              ["UTIL"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["INPUT_FIELD_LOCATION"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["MULTIPLE"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["SIZE"]=>
              int(40)
            }
          }
          ["collection":protected]=>
          *RECURSION*
          ["internalIndex":protected]=>
          int(0)
          ["isClone":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["fields":protected]=>
          object(Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields)#1684 (4) {
            ["values":protected]=>
            array(5) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(6) "140698"
              ["NAME"]=>
              string(6) "Имя"
              ["VALUE"]=>
              string(26) "Администратор"
              ["CODE"]=>
              string(3) "FIO"
              ["ORDER_PROPS_ID"]=>
              string(1) "1"
            }
            ["changedValues":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["originalValues":"Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields":private]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["isClone":protected]=>
            bool(false)
          }
          ["eventName":protected]=>
          NULL
        }

        ...

        [3]=>
        object(Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValue)#1683 (6) {
          ["property":protected]=>
          object(Bitrix\Sale\Property)#1676 (1) {
            ["fields":protected]=>
            array(29) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(2) "34"
              ["PERSON_TYPE_ID"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["NAME"]=>
              string(52) "ID заказа в платежной системе"
              ["TYPE"]=>
              string(6) "STRING"
              ["REQUIRED"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["SORT"]=>
              string(3) "100"
              ["USER_PROPS"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_LOCATION"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["PROPS_GROUP_ID"]=>
              string(1) "2"
              ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["IS_EMAIL"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_PROFILE_NAME"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_PAYER"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_LOCATION4TAX"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_FILTERED"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["CODE"]=>
              string(16) "PAYMENT_ORDER_ID"
              ["IS_ZIP"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_PHONE"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_ADDRESS"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["ACTIVE"]=>
              string(1) "Y"
              ["UTIL"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["INPUT_FIELD_LOCATION"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["MULTIPLE"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["MINLENGTH"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["MAXLENGTH"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["PATTERN"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["MULTILINE"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["SIZE"]=>
              string(0) ""
            }
          }
          ["collection":protected]=>
          *RECURSION*
          ["internalIndex":protected]=>
          int(3)
          ["isClone":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["fields":protected]=>
          object(Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields)#1757 (4) {
            ["values":protected]=>
            array(5) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(6) "140701"
              ["NAME"]=>
              string(52) "ID заказа в платежной системе"
              ["VALUE"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["CODE"]=>
              string(16) "PAYMENT_ORDER_ID"
              ["ORDER_PROPS_ID"]=>
              string(2) "34"
            }
            ["changedValues":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["originalValues":"Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields":private]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["isClone":protected]=>
            bool(false)
          }
          ["eventName":protected]=>
          NULL
        }
        [4]=>
        object(Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValue)#1672 (6) {
          ["property":protected]=>
          object(Bitrix\Sale\Property)#1761 (1) {
            ["fields":protected]=>
            array(29) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(2) "35"
              ["PERSON_TYPE_ID"]=>
              string(1) "1"
              ["NAME"]=>
              string(64) "Количество использованных бонусов"
              ["TYPE"]=>
              string(6) "STRING"
              ["REQUIRED"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["DEFAULT_VALUE"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["SORT"]=>
              string(3) "100"
              ["USER_PROPS"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_LOCATION"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["PROPS_GROUP_ID"]=>
              string(1) "2"
              ["DESCRIPTION"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["IS_EMAIL"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_PROFILE_NAME"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_PAYER"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_LOCATION4TAX"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_FILTERED"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["CODE"]=>
              string(14) "BONUSES_AMOUNT"
              ["IS_ZIP"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_PHONE"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["IS_ADDRESS"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["ACTIVE"]=>
              string(1) "Y"
              ["UTIL"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["INPUT_FIELD_LOCATION"]=>
              string(1) "0"
              ["MULTIPLE"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["MINLENGTH"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["MAXLENGTH"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["PATTERN"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["MULTILINE"]=>
              string(1) "N"
              ["SIZE"]=>
              string(0) ""
            }
          }
          ["collection":protected]=>
          *RECURSION*
          ["internalIndex":protected]=>
          int(4)
          ["isClone":protected]=>
          bool(false)
          ["fields":protected]=>
          object(Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields)#1762 (4) {
            ["values":protected]=>
            array(5) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(6) "140702"
              ["NAME"]=>
              string(64) "Количество использованных бонусов"
              ["VALUE"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["CODE"]=>
              string(14) "BONUSES_AMOUNT"
              ["ORDER_PROPS_ID"]=>
              string(2) "35"
            }
            ["changedValues":protected]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["originalValues":"Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields":private]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["isClone":protected]=>
            bool(false)
          }
          ["eventName":protected]=>
          NULL
        }
        ...

        [23]=>
        object(Bitrix\Sale\PropertyValue)#1420 (6) {
          ["property":protected]=>
          object(Bitrix\Sale\Property)#1735 (1) {
            ...
          }
          ...
        }
      }
    }
    ["internalIndex":protected]=>
    int(9)
    ["isClone":protected]=>
    bool(false)
    ["fields":protected]=>
    object(Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields)#1777 (4) {
      ["values":protected]=>
      array(5) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(6) "140707"
        ["NAME"]=>
        string(14) "Телефон"
        ["VALUE"]=>
---------   string(11) "79995488722" !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        ["CODE"]=>
        string(5) "PHONE"
        ["ORDER_PROPS_ID"]=>
        string(1) "3"
      }
      ["changedValues":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["originalValues":"Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields":private]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["isClone":protected]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    ["eventName":protected]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Я много гуглила, как поняла, нужно как то через reflection class написать получение value.

Все это нужно для сайта на битриксе, где в /local/php_interface/init.php при событии в момент изменения статуса оплаты любого заказа - должна срабатывать функция, где мне нужно получить id и телефон покупателя. Вот мой код в init.php:

```html
AddEventHandler("sale", "OnSalePayOrder", "UpdateAccountBonus"); // событие изменения статуса оплаты заказа
function UpdateAccountBonus($order_id, $status) {

    if ( $status == "Y" ) { // если заказ оплачен

        $order = Sale\Order::load($order_id);
        // $fields = $order->getField('PHONE');
        $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();
        $phonePropValue = $propertyCollection->getPhone();
        $ar = $propertyCollection->getGroupProperties(1);


        $r = new ReflectionClass($ar[0][1]); // выше в /bonus_log.php выведен $ar[0]
        $prop = $r->getProperty('fields');
        $prop->setAccessible(true);
        $fields = $prop->getValue($ar[0][1]);


        ob_flush();
        ob_start();
        var_dump($order_id);
        var_dump($status);
        var_dump($ar[0]); // вот этот вывод сокращенно выше показан
        $f=fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bonus_log.php", "w");
        fwrite($f, ob_get_flush());
        fclose($f);
    }


    // if ($order_id > 0 && $status == 'Y' && $order['CANCELED'] == "N") { // Заказ считается оплаченным

    // }
}
```

Сейчас не работает вывод $fields, отдает пустоту. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться! Я уже неделю в тупике((( php знаю очень базово, возможно решение простое, но я просто не знаю даже, как написать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler('sale', 'OnSaleStatusOrder',  array("CSaleHandler", "OnSaleStatusOrder"));


class CSaleHandler{
    public function OnSaleStatusOrder($id,$val){
        $order= \Bitrix\Sale\Order::load($id);
               
        $db_vals = CSaleOrderPropsValue::GetList(
            array(),
            array(
                "ORDER_ID" => $id,
            )
        );
        while ($arVals = $db_vals->Fetch()) {
            $prop[$arVals["CODE"]]=$arVals["VALUE"];
        }
        
        echo $prop["PHONE"];
       
    }
}
```

или на д7

```
class CSaleHandler{
    public function OnSaleStatusOrder($id,$val){
        $order= \Bitrix\Sale\Order::load($id);
               
        $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();

        $ar = $propertyCollection->getArray();

        $phonePropValue = $propertyCollection->getPhone(); // если отмечена галочка "являеться телефоном"
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

То, что прислали - почти подошло! Спасибо огромное!
Пришлось только немного адаптировать и номер телефона я из массива получила)))
Вот что в итоге получилось:

```html
include_once ("handlers.php");
include_once ("functions.php");
include_once ("SaleOrderHandler.php");

use Bitrix\Main;
use Bitrix\Sale;
use Bitrix\Main\PhoneNumber;
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;
use Artamonov\Api\Init as Api;

Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler(
    'sale',
    'OnSaleOrderCanceled',
    'OnSaleBeforeOrderCanceledHandlers'
);



// \Bitrix\Main\EventManager::getInstance()->addEventHandler('sale', 'OnSaleStatusOrder',  array("CSaleHandler", "OnSalePayStatusOrder"));
AddEventHandler("sale", "OnSalePayOrder", array("CSaleHandler", "OnSalePayStatusOrder")); // событие изменения статуса оплаты заказа

class CSaleHandler{
    public function OnSalePayStatusOrder($id,$status){

        if ( $status == "Y" ) { // если заказ оплачен

            $order = Sale\Order::load($id);

            $propertyCollection = $order->getPropertyCollection();

            $ar = $propertyCollection->getArray();

        // $phonePropValue = $propertyCollection->getPhone(); // если отмечена галочка "являеться телефоном"
        
        // ДОСТАЛА НОМЕР ТЕЛЕФОНА!
            $phoneProp = "";
            foreach ($ar["properties"] as $key => $prop) {
                if ( $prop["NAME"] == "Телефон" ) {
                    $phoneProp = $prop["VALUE"][0];
                }
            }

            ob_flush();
            ob_start();
            var_dump($ar);
            $f=fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/bonus_log.php", "w");
            fwrite($f, ob_get_flush());
            fclose($f);
        }
       
    }
}
```

Сейчас ломаю голову, как достать id покупателя, там при оформлении заказа регистрация идет нового пользователя и мне нужен его id - но в полученном тут массиве его нет..